# Appending structured data to a class attribute in Python

Tags: python, class, design-patterns

I have a couple of objects I'm using for running numerical simulations.  A minimal example is shown below where there are two objects: 1) an `Environment` object which has two states (x and y) that it simulates stochastically through time; and 2) a `Simulation` object which manages the simulaton and saves the state of the Environment throughout the simulation.

Within the Simulation object, I want to save the state of the Environment both 1) through time, and 2) across multiple simulations.  Through time I can use a defaultdict to save the state variables within a single simulation but across simulations it's not clear to me the best way to save the defaultdicts that have been generated.  If I append to a list (without using copy) then the list returns all identical defaultdicts due to the mutability of lists.  In the example below I use `copy.copy`, as the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) suggests.

Are there approaches that are more "Pythonic"?  Would it be better to use an immutable type to store the defaultdicts for each simulation?

```
import copy
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


class Environment(object):
    """
    Class representing a random walk of two variables x and y

    Methods
    -------
    start_simulation:   draw values from state variables from priors
    step:               add random noise to state variables
    current_state:      return current state of x and y in a dict

    """
    def __init__(self, mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2):
        self.mu1 = mu1
        self.mu2 = mu2
        self.sigma1 = sigma1
        self.sigma2 = sigma2

    def start_simulation(self):
        self.x = self.mu1 + self.sigma1 * np.random.randn()
        self.y = self.mu2 + self.sigma2 * np.random.randn()

    def step(self):
        self.x += self.sigma1 * np.random.randn()
        self.y += self.sigma2 * np.random.randn()

    def current_state(self):
        return({"x": self.x, "y": self.y})


class Simulation(object):
    """
    Class representing a simulation object for handling the Environment object
     and storing data

    Methods
    -------

    start_simulation:   start the simulation; initialise state of the environment
    simulate:           generate n_simulations simulations of n_timesteps time steps each
    save_state:          
    """
    def __init__(self, env, n_timesteps):
        self.env = env
        self.n_timesteps = n_timesteps

        self.data_all = []
        self.data_states = defaultdict(list)

    def start_simulation(self):
        self.timestep = 0
        self.env.start_simulation()

        # Append current data (if non empty)
        if self.data_states:
            self.data_all.append(copy.copy(self.data_states)) # <---------- this step
            # without copy.copy this will return all elements of the list data_all to be the 
            # same default dict at the end of all simulations - lists are mutable

        # Reset data_current
        self.data_states = defaultdict(list)

    def simulate(self, n_simulations):
        """
        Run simulation for n_simulations and n_timesteps timesteps
        """
        self.start_simulation()

        for self.simulation in range(n_simulations):

            self.timestep = 0

            while(self.timestep < self.n_timesteps):
                self.env.step()
                self.save_state(self.env.current_state())
                self.timestep += 1

            self.start_simulation()


    def save_state(self, state):
        """
        Save results to a default dict
        """
        for key, value in state.items():
            self.data_states[key].append(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Run 7 simulations, each for for 20 time steps
    N_TIME = 20
    N_SIM = 7

    e = Environment(
        mu1 = 1.4, sigma1 = 0.1, 
        mu2 = 2.6, sigma2 = 0.05)

    s = Simulation(env = e, n_timesteps = N_TIME)
    s.simulate(N_SIM)

    # Plot output
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for var, c in zip(["x", "y"], ["#D55E00", "#009E73"]):
        [ax.plot(pd.DataFrame(d)[var], label = var, color = c) for d in s.data_all]
    ax.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax.set_ylabel("Value")
    plt.show()
```

[image: random walkspython]

Comment: I have already a problem with the naming: You have a `Simulation` object which is actually container for multiple simulations (their data).

Comment: Good point.  I can adjust to name it `Container`?

Comment: `Container` or e. g. more specific `SimulationContainer` can be names for it. Also in the shown code the `copy.copy` seems not necessary because immediately after it you assign a new `defaultdict` to `self.data_states`. This means you are throwing away the original dict (including the lists only referenced by it) immediately after creating the copy. Then you can just use the original dict instead.

Comment: If I remove the `copy.copy` then the final list of all data (`data_all`) contains all the same object.

Comment: I checked this with a `print(repr(s.data_all))` near the end of your sample code (and removed `copy.copy`) and couldn't reproduce the problem. All defaultdicts contain lists with different values.